# css static header in row 1 does not line up with table rows

Tags: html, css, html-table

This is a simple little table with header and footer all css and html the top header remains fixed if you scroll however;

My header columns do not line up with the table columns.  Does anyone see what I am doing wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style type="text/css">
p {
    margin:0 0 1em ;
}
table p {
    margin:0;
}
.wrap {
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
    padding:0 0 0;
    border:7px solid #CCCCCC;
  /*   width:1800px;            */
}
.inner2 {
    float:left;
  /*  width:1800px;     */
    height:570px;
    position:relative;
    padding:60px 0 17px;
    overflow-y:hidden;
    overflow-x:auto;
}
.inner {
  /*   width:1800px;        */
    float:left;
    height:570px;
    overflow-y:auto;
    overflow-x:hidden;
}
.ylw {
    background-color:yellow;
}
.rd {
    background-color:red;
}
.grn {
    background-color:#339966;
}
table {
  /*   width:1800px;        */
    margin:0 0 0 0;
    border-collapse:collapse;
    float:left;
}
td {
    padding:0 0 0 0;
    border:1px solid #000000;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:14px;
}
tfoot th, thead th {
    font-weight:bold;
    text-align:center;
    border:1px solid #000000;
    padding:0 0 0 0;
    font-size:14px;
}
thead th {
    border:1px solid #000000;
    text-align:center;
    padding:0 0 0 0;
    }
thead tr p {
    margin: 0 0 0 -7px; 
    font-size:14px;
    position:absolute;
    text-align:center;
    padding:0 0 0 0;
    top:0;
}
.last {
    padding-right:15px!important;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Table with fixed header</h1>
<p>Notes: The header is part of the same table and not a separate table on top. The width of the table cells or header cells is not defined and will match whatever content is in the cells. The table can be a fluid length and will resize within reasonable limits accordingly.</p>
<p>You will be limited by the position of the header rows elements though as they can't really me moved around anymore thatn they are now.</p>
<div class='wrap'>
    <div class='inner2'>
        <div class='inner'>
            <table id='data' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th><p>Jan</p></th>
                        <th><p>Feb</p></th>
                        <th><p>Mar</p></th>
                        <th><p>Apr</p></th>
                        <th><p>May</p></th>
                        <th><p>Jun</p></th>
                        <th><p>Jul</p></th>
                        <th><p>Aug</p></th>
                        <th><p>September</p></th>
                        <th><p>Oct</p></th>
                        <th><p>Nov</p></th>
                        <th class='last'><p>Dec</p></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tfoot>
                    <tr>
                        <th><p>Jan</p></th>
                        <th><p>Feb</p></th>
                        <th><p>Mar</p></th>
                        <th><p>Apr</p></th>
                        <th><p>May</p></th>
                        <th><p>Jun</p></th>
                        <th><p>Jul</p></th>
                        <th><p>Aug</p></th>
                        <th><p>September</p></th>
                        <th><p>Oct</p></th>
                        <th><p>Nov</p></th>
                        <th class='last'><p>Dec</p></th>
                    </tr>
                </tfoot>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>3</td>
                        <td>5</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>3</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>5</td>
                        <td>7</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td class='last'>3</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>3</td>
                        <td>5</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>3</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>3 more data</td>
                        <td>5</td>
                        <td class='last'>7</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>2</td>
                        <td>4</td>
                        <td>6</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>3</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>23</td>
                        <td>4</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>6</td>
                        <td class='last'>6</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>6</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>4</td>
                        <td>7</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>7</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>3</td>
                        <td class='last'>6</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>2</td>
                        <td>3 with more data</td>
                        <td>2</td>
                        <td>3</td>
                        <td>3</td>
                        <td>3</td>
                        <td>8</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>2</td>
                        <td>8</td>
                        <td class='last'>6</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>6</td>
                        <td>4</td>
                        <td>4</td>
                        <td>4</td>
                        <td>2</td>
                        <td>9</td>
                        <td>4</td>
                        <td>4</td>
                        <td>6</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td class='last'>3</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>3</td>
                        <td>7</td>
                        <td>4</td>
                        <td>5</td>
                        <td>5</td>
                        <td>2</td>
                        <td>0</td>
                        <td>3</td>
                        <td>23</td>
                        <td class='last'>6</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>7</td>
                        <td>4</td>
                        <td>2</td>
                        <td>67</td>
                        <td>2</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>3</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>4</td>
                        <td>4</td>
                        <td class='last'>4</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>2</td>
                        <td>4</td>
                        <td>3</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>3</td>
                        <td>2</td>
                        <td>2</td>
                        <td>5</td>
                        <td>65</td>
                        <td class='last'>4</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>2</td>
                        <td>4</td>
                        <td>4</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>2</td>
                        <td>13</td>
                        <td>6</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>3</td>
                        <td>7</td>
                        <td class='last'>4</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>3</td>
                        <td>5</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>3</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>5</td>
                        <td>7</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td class='last'>3</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>3</td>
                        <td>5</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>3</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>3 more data</td>
                        <td>5</td>
                        <td class='last'>7</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>2</td>
                        <td>4</td>
                        <td>6</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>3</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>23</td>
                        <td>4</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>6</td>
                        <td class='last'>6</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>6</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>4</td>
                        <td>7</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>7</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>3</td>
                        <td class='last'>6</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>2</td>
                        <td>3 with more data</td>
                        <td>2</td>
                        <td>3</td>
                        <td>3</td>
                        <td>3</td>
                        <td>8</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>2</td>
                        <td>8</td>
                        <td class='last'>6</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>6</td>
                        <td>4</td>
                        <td>4</td>
                        <td>4</td>
                        <td>2</td>
                        <td>9</td>
                        <td>4</td>
                        <td>4</td>
                        <td>6</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td class='last'>3</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>3</td>
                        <td>7</td>
                        <td>4</td>
                        <td>5</td>
                        <td>5</td>
                        <td>2</td>
                        <td>0</td>
                        <td>3</td>
                        <td>23</td>
                        <td class='last'>6</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>7</td>
                        <td>4</td>
                        <td>2</td>
                        <td>67</td>
                        <td>2</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>3</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>4</td>
                        <td>4</td>
                        <td class='last'>4</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>2</td>
                        <td>4</td>
                        <td>3</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>3</td>
                        <td>2</td>
                        <td>2</td>
                        <td>5</td>
                        <td>65</td>
                        <td class='last'>4</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>2</td>
                        <td>4</td>
                        <td>4</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>2</td>
                        <td>13</td>
                        <td>6</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>3</td>
                        <td>7</td>
                        <td class='last'>4</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>3</td>
                        <td>5</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>3</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>5</td>
                        <td>7</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td class='last'>3</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>3</td>
                        <td>5</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>3</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>3 more data</td>
                        <td>5</td>
                        <td class='last'>7</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>2</td>
                        <td>4</td>
                        <td>6</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>3</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>23</td>
                        <td>4</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>6</td>
                        <td class='last'>6</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>6</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>4</td>
                        <td>7</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>7</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>3</td>
                        <td class='last'>6</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>2</td>
                        <td>3 with more data</td>
                        <td>2</td>
                        <td>3</td>
                        <td>3</td>
                        <td>3</td>
                        <td>8</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>2</td>
                        <td>8</td>
                        <td class='last'>6</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>6</td>
                        <td>4</td>
                        <td>4</td>
                        <td>4</td>
                        <td>2</td>
                        <td>9</td>
                        <td>4</td>
                        <td>4</td>
                        <td>6</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td class='last'>3</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>3</td>
                        <td>7</td>
                        <td>4</td>
                        <td>5</td>
                        <td>5</td>
                        <td>2</td>
                        <td>0</td>
                        <td>3</td>
                        <td>23</td>
                        <td class='last'>6</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>7</td>
                        <td>4</td>
                        <td>2</td>
                        <td>67</td>
                        <td>2</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>3</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>4</td>
                        <td>4</td>
                        <td class='last'>4</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>2</td>
                        <td>4</td>
                        <td>3</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>3</td>
                        <td>2</td>
                        <td>2</td>
                        <td>5</td>
                        <td>65</td>
                        <td class='last'>4</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>2</td>
                        <td>4</td>
                        <td>4</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>2</td>
                        <td>13</td>
                        <td>6</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>3</td>
                        <td>7</td>
                        <td class='last'>4</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>3</td>
                        <td>5</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>3</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>5</td>
                        <td>7</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td class='last'>3</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>3</td>
                        <td>5</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>3</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>3 more data</td>
                        <td>5</td>
                        <td class='last'>7</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>2</td>
                        <td>4</td>
                        <td>6</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>3</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>23</td>
                        <td>4</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>6</td>
                        <td class='last'>6</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>6</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>4</td>
                        <td>7</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>7</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>3</td>
                        <td class='last'>6</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>2</td>
                        <td>3 with more data</td>
                        <td>2</td>
                        <td>3</td>
                        <td>3</td>
                        <td>3</td>
                        <td>8</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>2</td>
                        <td>8</td>
                        <td class='last'>6</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>6</td>
                        <td>4</td>
                        <td>4</td>
                        <td>4</td>
                        <td>2</td>
                        <td>9</td>
                        <td>4</td>
                        <td>4</td>
                        <td>6</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td class='last'>3</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>3</td>
                        <td>7</td>
                        <td>4</td>
                        <td>5</td>
                        <td>5</td>
                        <td>2</td>
                        <td>0</td>
                        <td>3</td>
                        <td>23</td>
                        <td class='last'>6</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>7</td>
                        <td>4</td>
                        <td>2</td>
                        <td>67</td>
                        <td>2</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>3</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>4</td>
                        <td>4</td>
                        <td class='last'>4</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>2</td>
                        <td>4</td>
                        <td>3</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>3</td>
                        <td>2</td>
                        <td>2</td>
                        <td>5</td>
                        <td>65</td>
                        <td class='last'>4</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>2</td>
                        <td>4</td>
                        <td>4</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>2</td>
                        <td>13</td>
                        <td>6</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>3</td>
                        <td>7</td>
                        <td class='last'>4</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>3</td>
                        <td>5</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>3</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>5</td>
                        <td>7</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td class='last'>3</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>3</td>
                        <td>5</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>3</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>3 more data</td>
                        <td>5</td>
                        <td class='last'>7</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>2</td>
                        <td>4</td>
                        <td>6</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>3</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>23</td>
                        <td>4</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>6</td>
                        <td class='last'>6</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>6</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>4</td>
                        <td>7</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>7</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>3</td>
                        <td class='last'>6</td>
                    </tr>
               <tr>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>3</td>
                        <td>5</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>3</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>3 more data</td>
                        <td>5</td>
                        <td class='last'>7</td>
                    </tr>
                 </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are absolutely positioning and have negative margins on your P tags within the TH tags

this rule: **thead tr p** try zeroing out the margin on that rule.

```
thead tr p {
     margin: 0; /* zero out margin */

     font-size: 14px;
     position: absolute;
     text-align: center;
     padding: 0;
     top: 0;
}
```

if you want the **text-align:center** to work when absolutely positioning the P tags.. you will need to add a specific **width** to them

**EDIT:**

you also have your TFOOT below your THEAD instead of being after the TBODY

http://jsfiddle.net/MP8Bc/

it lines up but they are aligned left... and wont align center unless you add widths since they are absolutely positioned , which means they are out of the document flow

Comment: tried that i changed  margin: 0 0 0 -7px; 
to   margin: 0; /* zero out margin */
it did not change.

Comment: tried margin 0; and text-align; Left; on the thead tr p.  no change.

Comment: I am using ie 8 that may be the reason yours looks ok and mine is not changing?   I could not get the jsfiddle site to load here.

Comment: ooohh i see .. i didnt check IE8 .. IE8 is horrible with positioning, check out this jsfiddle in IE8.. it is in full view since jsfiddle has issues with displaying in IE8 with full code view -- http://jsfiddle.net/MP8Bc/embedded/result/ --

Comment: yes, it works for ie 11, I don't have ie8 any more.